# Regex for WhatsApp Chat Log

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to return WhatsApp conversation as an array.
To do so, I am utilizing regex, however I can't get it to work.

This is a sample chat as exported via WhatsApp (edited):

```
6/13/18, 3:40 AM - Messages to this group are now secured with end-to-end encryption. Tap for more info.
6/13/18, 3:40 AM - You created group "Test Group"
6/13/18, 3:42 AM - Zack added Emma
6/13/18, 4:06 AM - Zack added Json
6/13/18, 2:35 PM - Zack: Let's meet tomorrow.
6/15/18, 5:34 PM - Emma: I'll create the Discord server by tonight.
We'll look into making the parser.
7/15/18, 12:05 PM - Zack: Great, I'll add that to our schedule.
7/15/18, 12:05 PM - Json: On our team calander - TCal?
7/15/18, 12:05 PM - Zack: Yes, added on 7/15/18, 12:05 PM.
7/15/18, 12:05 PM - Emma: Are we going JS on this?
7/15/18, 12:05 PM - Json: You bet.
7/15/18, 12:05 PM - Zack: JS is love, JS is life.
7/15/18, 1:46 PM - Emma: Haha.
7/15/18, 4:53 PM - Json:
```

I've tried the following:

```
/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2},\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s[AP]M\s-.+\n?/g
```

which as you'd expect gets me the lines as follows:
 -

...but if the message has more than 1 line then that gets skipped.

e.g

> 6/15/18, 5:34 PM - Emma: I'll create the Discord server by
>   tonight.
>  We'll look into making the parser.

extracts:

> 6/15/18, 5:34 PM - Emma: I'll create the Discord server by tonight.

but I would like it to extract as:

> Emma: I'll create the Discord server by tonight.
>  We'll look into
>   making the parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use your (a bit shortened) pattern  inside a positive lookahead:

```
s.split(/(?=^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2},\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s[AP]M)/m).filter(Boolean)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zaBeMU/1)

Here, the pattern will match each line start position that is immediately followed with the `\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2},\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s[AP]M)` pattern.

JS Demo:

```js
var s = "6/13/18, 3:40 AM - Messages to this group are now secured with end-to-end encryption. Tap for more info.\r\n6/13/18, 3:40 AM - You created group \"Test Group\"\r\n6/13/18, 3:42 AM - Zack added Emma\r\n6/13/18, 4:06 AM - Zack added Json\r\n6/13/18, 2:35 PM - Zack: Let's meet tomorrow.\r\n6/15/18, 5:34 PM - Emma: I'll create the Discord server by tonight.\r\nWe'll look into making the parser.\r\n7/15/18, 12:05 PM - Zack: Great, I'll add that to our schedule.\r\n7/15/18, 12:05 PM - Json: On our team calander - TCal?\r\n7/15/18, 12:05 PM - Zack: Yes, added on 7/15/18, 12:05 PM.\r\n7/15/18, 12:05 PM - Emma: Are we going JS on this?\r\n7/15/18, 12:05 PM - Json: You bet.\r\n7/15/18, 12:05 PM - Zack: JS is love, JS is life.\r\n7/15/18, 1:46 PM - Emma: Haha.\r\n7/15/18, 4:53 PM - Json: ";
console.log(s.split(/(?=^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2},\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s[AP]M)/m).filter(Boolean));
```

You may trim each item in the resulting array if you add `.map(x => x.trim())` (or `.map(function(x) { return x.trim(); })`).

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Nice that it works, I just wanted to give a heads-up that the export format depends heavily on your system language.

E.g. 02/12/12 11 PM (English) vs 23:00 12/02/12 (German) So your current solution will only handle some cases.

Also, System messages or attachments will later create issues for you.

I faced the same issue when building a tool to analzye WhatsApp Chats and used a [Javascript library](https://github.com/Pustur/whatsapp-chat-parser) which uses multiple regex expressions which cover almost all corner cases:

Filtering general:

```
const regexParser = /^(?:\u200E|\u200F)*\[?(\d{1,4}[-/.] ?\d{1,4}[-/.] ?\d{1,4})[,.]? \D*?(\d{1,2}[.:]\d{1,2}(?:[.:]\d{1,2})?)(?: ([ap]\.? ?m\.?))?\]?(?: -|:)? (.+?): ([^]*)/i;
```

Filter System Messages:

```
const regexParserSystem = /^(?:\u200E|\u200F)*\[?(\d{1,4}[-/.] ?\d{1,4}[-/.] ?\d{1,4})[,.]? \D*?(\d{1,2}[.:]\d{1,2}(?:[.:]\d{1,2})?)(?: ([ap]\.? ?m\.?))?\]?(?: -|:)? ([^]+)/i;
```

Date:

```
const regexSplitDate = /[-/.] ?/;
```

Handle attachments, which are passed in "< >" even when you export the chat without attachments. (e.g. <media ommitted>)

```
const regexAttachment = /<.+:(.+)>/;`
```